# jQuery FadeIn() evokes "jump" of the faded in picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, joomla, content-management-system

I have an imagemap. On a click a `jQuery function` is called which evokes several `fadeIn()`.
All this is happening in the Joomla CMS. 
Locally, and in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/12mLzagn/) it works just fine (to trigger the `fadeIn()` click on the "¡Tocame!". 
But on this site http://fonag.org.ec/inicio/link7b the images which are faded in seem to jump.

```
 //FADEIN FUNCTION JQUERY
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#toca").click(function() { 
     $("#step1D").fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
     $("#step2D").delay(2000).fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
     $("#step3D").delay(4000).fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(550);
     $("#step4D").delay(60000).fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
     $("#plato").delay(8000).fadeIn(5000);
     });
 });


 <!--POSTINIONING -->
 <div class="fadein" style="position: relative;" width="655" height="338">

 <!-- HIDDEN PRELOADED IMAGES FOR HIGHLIGHT-->
 <div id="step1D" style="display: none; position: absolute;" width="655" height="338"></div>
 <div id="step2D" style="display: none; position: absolute;" width="655" height="338"></div>
 <div id="step3D" style="display: none; position: absolute;" width="655" height="338"></div>
<div id="step4D" style="display: none; position: absolute;" width="655" height="338"></div>

 <!-- INSERT THE PICTURE IMAGEMAP--> 
 <img name="base" id="plato" src="http://www.fonag.org.ec/inicio/images/Slide/aprender_jugando/buenas_practicas/pag5/base.png" width="655" height="338" border="0" usemap="#m_base" alt="" /> 
 ....
 .....
```

Comment: Please provide the code necessary to reproduce the issue in code. This is not a *web site* debugging service...

Comment: @TJ I thought I provided the code which is necessary. The `faceIn()` function and the positioning of the images. Thats where **I** think lays the problem. If you think the problem is somewhere else, let me know where you think it could be and I provide the code which is needed. But apart from that, the whole code is in the JSFiddle.

Comment: No,  You yourself said *"and in this JSFiddle it works just fine"* - Which means you know the problem isn't with the code provided. It is very obvious that the problem is specific to your website. Such questions are off topic here. *"If you think the problem is somewhere else, let me know where you think it could be"* - The problem is with the website. I'm not interested in following that link to figure out what the issue is since it is very specific to you and isn't likely to help anyone in future.

Comment: @TJ ah, now I understand your post. Well I think there are a lot of specific topics here. Furthermore, this could be a general problem in Joomla and the usage of div frames and its positioning.

Comment: Might be due to the fact you have 4 copies of jQuery being imported which can cause conflicts and issues like this. Please make sure you have **only 1** instance of it imported. For this, you can use an extension such as *jQueryEasy*

Comment: @Lodder I have that PlugIn already installed and configured...